# How can I improve this sql query performance?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

SQL statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM ACT_CARD_BANK
WHERE CARD_NO IN (SELECT CARD_NO
                  FROM XSHTEST.XSH_CARD_BANK
                  WHERE BIN_NO IN ('731018', '731023', '731024', '731025', '731026', '731027')
                    AND STATUS = '06')
  AND STATUS = '04';
```

[execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Unh5.png)

[Index 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPf61.png)

[Index 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrOhL.png)

Rows of the table:

```
ACT_CARD_BANK  399187646
XSH_CARD_BANK  228751942
```

The statistics were re-collected yesterday with the following script:

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(ownname => '$owner',tabname => 'XSH_CARD_BANK',estimate_percent => 0.1,method_opt=> 'for all indexed columns');
```

Is there anything else I can optimize? Thank you.

Comment: Performance troubleshooting is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Have you tried Joining of 2 tables ACT_CARD_BANK, XSHTEST.XSH_CARD_BANK where both have card no. as a common link ? If yes , what was the performance and it would look cleaner as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure the query is using appropriate indexes.
2. Use table aliases to make the query easier to read and understand.
3. Use a JOIN instead of a subquery.
4. Use bulk operations to reduce the number of round trips to the database.
5. Use appropriate query hints to force the optimizer to use a more efficient query plan.
6. Use table partitioning to reduce the amount of data that needs to be scanned.
7. Use stored procedures to reduce the amount of code that needs to be parsed and optimized.

```sql
    SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM ACT_CARD_BANK AS a
    INNER JOIN XSHTEST.XSH_CARD_BANK AS b
    ON a.CARD_NO = b.CARD_NO
    WHERE b.BIN_NO IN ('731018', '731023', '731024', '731025', '731026', '731027') AND b.STATUS = '06' AND a.STATUS = '04'
```